# Filter list in Struts 1.3

Tags: java, list, jsp, drop-down-menu, struts-1

I'm new to struts. I want to filter a list which gets displayed as a drop down on JSP page.

**SelectClient.jsp:**

```
<%@ include file="/tiles/taglibs.inc"%>
<div class='block'>
  <h1><bean:message key='selectClient.header' /></h1> 
  <form name='selectClientForm' action='/index.do' method='post'> 
    <table align='center' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
    <tr>
      <td height='400px' valign='middle'>
        <bean:message key='selectClient.text'/>
        <gema:permissionSelect name='userInfo' property='client'>
          <html:options name='userInfo' property='possibleClients'/>
        </gema:permissionSelect>
      </td>  
    </tr>
    </table>
      <ul class='buttons'>
        <li>
          <gema:permissionButton action='/index.do' target='selectClient' formName='selectClientForm' defaultButton='true'>
            <bean:message key='global.action.accept' />
          </gema:permissionButton>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </form>
</div>
```

The model class used here is **userInfo**. But in my project it is part of library, so I can't edit it.

```
public class UserInfo implements Serializable {
    private List<String> possibleClients = null;
    ...............  }
```

There is a **struts-config.xml** file used in the project which has **selectClient** attribute used as follows

```
  <global-forwards>
    <forward name='selectClient' module='/' path='.selectClient' redirect='true'/>
  </global-forwards>
```

My question is how I can find a relevant class(POJO) or Controller which forwards **UserInfo** object to **selectClient** page, so that I can filter the list on java object.

There are some action paths present in struts-config.xml like below:

```
 <action path='/logout' type='de.gema.common.web.action.LogoutAction'>
  <forward name='success' path='/index.do' redirect='true'/>
  </action>
```

And as far as I know about **global-forwards** tag, they are used as a part of all action paths.
Which I can also see in my application, as I can change client anytime I want.

But when I tried to look into all action classes, I can't find the UserInfo object being used anywhere.

I also debugged **UserInfo.class** on Intellij and I figured out the object gets populated from database during application start up.

One approach could be to remove the required filtered attribute from database. So that it is not loaded on the first place.
However I would like to know, how can I filter it on Java side?

Comment: Not sure I understand--this is tagged as Struts 2 but the code looks like Struts 1; which is it? In any case, it's not clear what the issue is--it looks like the list is exposed via an action form, and you can do whatever you want to it before it's passed on to the view layer.

Comment: Hi, Thanks I edited my question and added more information. I cannot find the relevant action class for editing UserInfo object.

Comment: Find the action by looking at the URL and locating its matching action configuration.